# Change of default applications during upgrade

Tags: upgrade

LibreOffice and Banshee are set to replace OpenOffice and Rhythmbox as we move from 10.10 to 11.04. Doing a fresh install obviously makes these new applications the default ones.

However, if I choose to upgrade via the update manager, will the old applications be uninstalled and the new ones installed automatically as replacement, or do I have to do these manually so that I get the same experience as a fresh install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading will give you the new default applications but will not remove the old defaults because many people may not want the old applications to go away. For instance, Gimp used to be in the default install. Those that don't want the old applications are free to remove them manually.

The exception to this is if new tools conflict with previous tools, then the previous tools will be removed, but this shouldn't be the case with apps like music players or photo editors.

LibreOffice as far as I can see is replacing OpenOffice.org. The version of OpenOffice.org that Ubuntu and most other Linux distributions were shipping had several patches from Novell that Sun/Oracle never accepted but are now included in LibreOffice. I don't even think there will be a 3.3 build of OpenOffice.org in the Ubuntu repositories and trying to keep both installed isn't really useful.

Comment: just adding tou your answer, installing libreoffice will completely remove openoffice

Answer (score 2):

I always setup a second user on a new system. 
Then I log into that new user account to see what changes there are in comparison to my old user account which kept my settings (including my defaults!). 
Sometimes it's quite nice to see some changes for the good.

After that you get two options:

- change some settings in your old account to get some of the new goodies by working through the settings folders of your applications and conf-files in your home directory.
- or you use the new account and copy the settings folders and conf-files of the few applications you want to keep with their configurations and settings into the new home directory. (Obviously you have to do this as superuser via "sudo" and change the owner of those settings folders afterwards recursivly to the name of the new user/group.)

That way I always get the new concepts and my custom configuration within the brandnew system.